# Meteorjs collection.find won't return specific data from database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

as the title say when i pull collection.find works fine if I write normally

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function(){
      return Tasks.find({})
    }
```

but if I do this

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function(){
      return Tasks.find({}, {fields:{completed:"no"}})
    }
```

It won't pull from the database anymore

Answer (score 1):

Your field specification needs to evaluate to true/false:

Try:

```
return Tasks.find({}, { fields: { completed: 0 }})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOne or find as required:

```
return Tasks.find({}, {fields: {'completed': "no"}});
return Tasks.findOne({'completed':"no"});
```

Your syntax looks good. Check the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)

Make sure your filter is valid.

Comment: Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
    return Tasks.find({});
  });    This is my filter. i tried but for some reason it won't work